# Blazor, new layout Indexes

Tags: html, web-applications, blazor

I understand that in Blazor you can't have two pages with the page address as "/"

But say you're using a separate layout for the not found layout, how would you specify the default page?

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(NotFoundLayout)">
            <h1>404</h1>
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</NotFound>
```

In a Blazor app I set Index.razor to target MainLayour, with the page as "/",
I then created a not found page to target NotFoundLayout, with the page as "/" also.

I thought this would work but it did not.

So how would you specify the default page to be rendered in @body for the NotFoundLaout?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do such a thing ?

However, do the following:

Create your NotFoundLayout component like this:

NotFoundLayout.razor

---

```
  @inherits LayoutComponentBase

  <div class="main">
   <div class="content px-4">
      @Body
   </div>
  </div>


  @code {}
```

In App.razor use this:

```
<LayoutView Layout="@typeof(NotFoundLayout)">
        <h1>404</h1>
        <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
         <p>BlazorApp2 is the namespace where the Pages folder 
         resides, in which the Index component live. You can use a 
         using directive instead :)</P>
        <BlazorApp2.Pages.Index />
</LayoutView>
```

That is all. 
Note: All you have to do is render the Index component within the LayoutView element. Run your app, enter a faulty url, and you'll see '404' , 'Sorry, there's nothing at this address.', and the content rendered by the Index element. Remember, all the content within the opening LayoutView element and closing LayoutView element is of RenderFragment delegate type, known conventionally as ChildContent, and it is made available to your NotFoundLayout component via the LayoutComponentBase.Body parameter property

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ok, thanks. This makes sense. TBH, I was just asking the question because I had the hickup when following a guide. The person somehow achieved what I had mentioned. Unless he removed the Index page and did not list it in his steps :/

Comment: @Harley Torrisi, Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.